# Gulp ошибка uglify

Tags: javascript, css, gulp

```html
$('#design').on('click', ()=> {
    $('.project-nav__item').removeClass('active');
    $('.design').addClass('active');
    $('.portfolio-list__item').addClass('hide');
    $('.mans').removeClass('hide');
});

$('#filter').on('click', ()=> {
    $('.project-nav__item').removeClass('active');
    $('.all').addClass('active');
     $('.portfolio-list__item').removeClass('hide');
    });



$(window).scroll(function(){
 if($(window).scrollTop()>500){
  $('#header').css('background-image', 'linear-gradient(to right, #211b19 0%, #4e3427 100%)');
  $('#header').css('top', '0');
  $('#header').css('position', 'fixed')
} 
 else if ($(window).scrollTop()<50) {
  $('#header').css('background-image', 'none');
  $('#header').css('top', '40px');
  $('#header').css('position', 'absolute');
}
})


var menu = document.querySelector('.navigation');
scrollSpy(menu, 2000, 'easeInOutQuint');
```

```
gulp.task('js', function() {
    gulp.src([
                'js/jquery-1.11.3.min.js',
                'js/main.js',
                'js/modal.js',
                'js/scroll.js',

    ])
    .pipe(concat('main.min.js'))
    .pipe(uglify({mangle: true}))
    .pipe(gulp.dest('./public/js/'))
})
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
cmd выдает такое

Comment: Приложите файл `js/main.js`

Comment: Добавил в шапку

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Uglify` не умеет работать со стрелочными функциями. Пропустите ваш скрипт через `babel` или используете старый метод объявления функций.